# Concrete Mathematics chapter 2 infinite calculus (geometric series)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, geometric-series

Did the authors use **finite** **calculus** to evaluate this sum?
If so then how?
$$
  \sum_{k\ge0} x^k
= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}
= \begin{cases}
   \frac{1}{1-x} & \text{if $0 \leq x < 1$}, \\
   \infty  & \text{if $x \geq 1$}.
  \end{cases}
$$
The book is *Concrete Mathematics* by Knuth.

Thank you.

Comment: If $0 \le x < 1$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}x^n = 0$ and you get $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$. If $x \ge 1$ Then $\sum_{k \ge 0}x^k \ge \sum_{k \ge 0}1 \to \infty$ as $k \to \infty$.

Comment: No techniques the book calls finite calculus is used here, they first write the partial sums in a closed form and take the limit, which converges only for $|x|<1$

Comment: @TheoDiamantakis can you kindly write the procedure

Comment: ...they just outlined it for you. Find partial sums then take a limit.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I know how to do it with normal calculus but the authors developed a technique called Finite Calculus it includes difference operator and definite summation, I was wondering did they used that method because the very next example used that

Comment: My latex is awfully slow so others have already provided an answer, do you understand now? Feel free to ask if not. The most common proof is also found on wikipedia here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula

Comment: There is no use of the finite calculus here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you divide $1-x^{n+1}$ by $1-x$ you will get     $\sum_{k=0}^n x^k$

Now if $|x|<1$, then as $n\to \infty $, $x^{n+1}\to 0$

If $x\ge 1$ then the series diverges to $\infty$

Thus the result:
$$\sum_{k\ge0} x^k
= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}
= \begin{cases}
   \frac{1}{1-x} & \text{if $0 \leq x < 1$}, \\
   \infty  & \text{if $x \geq 1$}.
  \end{cases}$$